# Git diff between branch A & B, select a set of file mode changes, reset those changes to branch A

Tags: git, file-permissions, git-diff, git-reset

I would like to

Step 1) make Git diff between branch A & B,

Step 2) select a set of changes (select those changes, where file permission is changed from mode 100755 to mode 100644),

Step 3) reset those selected changes to branch A (or cherry pick changes from branch B).

How can I do with git?

**Partial solution:**

Step 1 & 2) I was able to list those files, which have

`git diff --name-only "A" "B" | grep 'mode change 100755 => 100644'`

Step 3) How can I reset those selected file mode changes to branch A (or cherry pick changes from branch B)?
I just want to restore the file states of files selected in step 1 to their state they had in branch A.

Note: I have several thousand files, so cherry picking one by one is not a solution.

**@jthill: Unfortunately, when doing chmod on MINGW64 (Windows) it has no effect, likely because of Windows.**

```
$ ls -la admin/langdoc.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 klor 197121 9844 Apr 25 23:04 admin/langdoc.php
$ chmod 755 admin/langdoc.php
$ ls -la admin/langdoc.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 klor 197121 9844 Apr 25 23:04 admin/langdoc.php
```

Because I'm developing in Windows, and repos are stored in Linux, the chmod based permission changes are not my way, because Windows doesn't support Linux-like 755 or 644 permissions.

**@jthill however gave me a good start to have a working solution. Thanks!**

**I found an improved way, which works on Windows & Linux, too, based on answer of @jthill:**

1. changing the permission/mode change internally within git, using

   ```
   git update-index --chmod=+x file.php
   ```

**Solution for**

**1. file mode changes: mode change 100755 => 100644**

```

```
# 1st line just creates a file to be able to check if mode of same files are changing
git diff --raw "A" "B" | sed -n '/^:100755 100644/ s/[^\t]*.//p' > diff_mode_100755.txt
# 2nd is doing the mode change from 100755 to 100644
git diff --raw "A" "B" | sed -n '/^:100755 100644/ s/[^\t]*.//p' | xargs -d\\n git update-index --chmod=+x
git commit -m "Restore original 755 file mode"
```

```

**2. file mode changes: mode change 100644 => 100755**

```

```
# 1st line just creates a file to be able to check if mode of same files are changing
git diff --raw "A" "B" | sed -n '/^:100644 100755/ s/[^\t]*.//p' > diff_mode_100644.txt
# 2nd is doing the mode change from 100644 to 100755
git diff --raw "A" "B" | sed -n '/^:100644 100755/ s/[^\t]*.//p' | xargs -d\\n git update-index --chmod=-x
git commit -m "Restore original 644 file mode"
```

```

Comment: You can cherry-pick commits by checking out the branch you want to apply the commits onto and use `git cherry-pick REVS` to specify the sha of the commit(s) you want to cherry-pick. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Basically yes, cherry pick those changes, which was selected in step 1 & 2. Modified my OP, see the changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git diff --raw A B | sed -n '/^:100755 100644/ s/[^\t]*.//p'
```

will list the paths you want to choose from, edit that and pipe it to `xargs -d\\n chmod` with a-x or a+x depending on whether you're on A and want to lose the x bit or on B and want to restore it.

On Windows, where the executable bit is meaningless you can just update the index entries directly, instead of `chmod a+x`ing the files then letting git add update the index, `git update-index --chmod=+x` the files to set the bit in the index, `-x` to clear it.

Comment: see my edit in OP. chmod has no effect in Windows (using Mingw64).

Answer (score 0):

Unclear what you mean by "reset".  Diff is not the same thing as the commits themselves that constitute the divergence.  Do you want all the commits that constitute those changes (w/ messages and authorship) or do you just want the net result?  It sounds like you are talking about creating a *new* set of changes on A based on a subset of changes in B.

To **cherry-pick** commits, review `git log B` to identify them, then on A:

```
git cherry-pick [COMMIT_HASH]
```

To **combine** or **decompose** cherry-picks into a single commit, do:

```
git cherry-pick --no-commit [COMMIT_HASH1]
git cherry-pick --no-commit [COMMIT_HASH2]
...
git commit -a
```

To **decompose** cherry-pick(s), i.e., cherry-pick changes *within* the commit(s):

```
git cherry-pick --no-commit [COMMIT_HASH]
...
git checkout some_file/we/dont/care/about
git checkout another/file/we/dont/care/about
...
git reset -p file/we/want/some/changes/from
git commit -a
```

The `checkout`s abandon the changes for given files.  The `reset -p` is interactive, like `git add -p` in reverse.  You've already picked some changes to the file and are picking changes to reset.  Anything you leave is part of the slimmed down cherry-pick that you will commit.

Lastly, if you just want **entire file changes** (i.e. "B's file is the right one") and you don't care about how it got there (commit metadata), then just checkout the file contents from that branch and commit them:

```
git checkout origin/B -- path/to/file
...
git commit -a
```

Comment: I modified my OP, maybe now it's more clear, what I want.

Answer (score 0):

The original question is for Windows but I had the same problem on Mac. @jthill's advice was very helpful, but the sed command was too greedy in my case – it would digest the first columns as well as half the file path, only leaving the last bits of each file name.

It seems that sed on Mac doesn't parse `\t` very well (it also doesn't seem to take `\s` for white space, generally). I ended up using the consistent column widths and deleting a set number of characters:

```
# Send diff to text file
git diff --raw master update_socio_eco > tmp-diff.txt

# Search for files with mode change from 644 to 755; delete initial 33 characters
# Swap order to 100755 100644 if reverting to 755
sed -nE '/:100644 100755/ s/^:.{32}//p' tmp-diff.txt >tmp-diff2.txt

# Add quotes to capture files with white space
sed -n 's/.*/"&"/p' tmp-diff2.txt >tmp-diff3.txt

# Change file mode (-x to revert to 644, +x to revert to 755)
cat tmp-diff3.txt | xargs chmod -x
```